# How to return from promise inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating my first custom hook. I would like the hook to return the `deviceType` which is the result of a `Promise` in the hook.

#### Hook:

```
export default function useDeviceType() {
  // Finds the user's device type and sets the
  // screen orientation appropriately.
  useEffect(() => {
    getDeviceTypeAsync().then((deviceType) => {
      const orientationPromise = setScreenOrientation(deviceType);
      return deviceType
    });
  }, []);
}
```

#### Use of hook:

```
export default function DevelopmentScreen() {
  const deviceType = useDeviceType();
  console.log(deviceType)
  return null;
}
```

##### Console:

> undefined

I may be having difficulty understanding the `useEffect` hook but I believe it should just fully run once here.

Is the item being returned still undefined because the `Promise` has not resolved? If so, then how am I able to use the `deviceType` inside `setScreenOrientation`?

When I `console.log(deviceType)` inside the `useEffect` hook I get the appropriate response:

> 2

Thank in advance for the help in understanding this!

##### Final Edit:

```
export default function useDeviceToSetOrientation() {
  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getDeviceTypeAsync().then((type) => {
      const orientationPromise = setScreenOrientation(type);
      orientationPromise.then((data) => {
        setOrientation(data);
      })
    });
  }, []);
  return orientation
};

export default function DevelopmentScreen() {
  const orientation = useDeviceToSetOrientation();
  console.log(orientation)
  return null;
}
```

##### Output (correct):

> 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
export default function useDeviceType() {
  const [deviceType, setDeviceType] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    getDeviceTypeAsync().then((type) => {
      const orientationPromise = setScreenOrientation(type);
      setDeviceType(type);
    });
  }, []);
  return deviceType
}
```

This should fix the behavior and then `deviceType` will be accessible through `const deviceType = useDeviceType();`.

What you seem to be misunderstanding here is how returning values from `useEffect` work. You can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup), but we actually use it to create cleanup functions that will run on our component's unmount.

Edit: you can also see in [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) how custom hooks are supposed to return values.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and external resources! I was reading the docs to build this hook but need to focus a little more on how they build them.

Comment: You're welcome! Hooks are a bit overwhelming at first but they're a really powerful tool. It is totally worth it to devote some time trying to figure them out :)

Comment: There's probably no need for that `orientationPromise` line. It seems a little superfluous. @DanielBaldi

Comment: My initial thought was to have the hook named `useDeviceToSetOrientation` then return the `orientationPromise` but now it seems that I can use a `useState` hook to `setOrientation` from the `orientationPromise` and then `return orientation`. Thoughts?

Comment: @Andy yeah, you're right! Maybe OP intends to improve legibility or feels more comfortable with this. I've just copied the original code and made changes to its structure!

Comment: @DavidAlford it seems like `screenOrientation` and `deviceType` will have the same value in your code. I don't see why you would split it in two different states but you could also return them both in your custom hook using `return [screenOrientation, deviceType]` or `return {screenOrientation, deviceType}`

Comment: Thank you for that.  I guess I should probably return the `deviceType` since `orientation` is obvious to the user holding the device :P .. added a final edit but going to revert to your suggestion :) Thanks for the help!